Continuous and perfect infinitives
What is the difference between continuous and perfect continuous infinitives while referring to the future. Don't they convey the same meaning? For instance

I want you to be doing your homework when I get home

I want you to have been doing your homework when I get home


Is there any difference?

I'm not sure what #2 would be supposed to mean. I certainly wouldn't endorse non-native speakers using such a convoluted verb form, whatever they wanted it to mean.

1 would mean that when I walk through the door I want to see you doing your homework at that time. 2 would mean that when I walk through the door I want to see either: you doing your homework at that time or evidence that, at that time, you have recently been doing your homework. For good measure, you could have had 3 I want you to have done your homework when I get home - when I when I walk through the door I want to see that you have completed your homework.

@MichaelHarvey so quite similar. I found on the internet that with 2 it is obligatory to state duartion like "I want you to have been doing your homework for 2 hour" or something. Do you think so or is my 2 example fine without that?

You don't have to state duration with to have been doing, if you don't, it is equivalent to saying I want you to have done at least some of your homework'.

@MichaelHarvey does the same apply to future perfect continuous that I don't have to state duration for instance "I will have been playing when they visit" would be fine with no duration?

@MichaelHarvey There are some long angsty threads here about whether "I read that book" means "I finished it" or "I spent time reading it"; similar quibbles could be raised ("Well, you just said do my homework, and I diiiiid my homework... you didn't say all of it...") Meanwhile, I side with FumbleFingers: #2 is nonsense. The literal meaning (at a designated point in the future I want your then-present state to be informed by a recent past of ongoing indeterminate action) is just not a meaning we find ourselves needing to convey outside of Star Trek time-travel episodes. The closest...

... The closest equivalent I could imagine, not bringing the "done = completion" sense in, is "I want you to have spent some time doing your homework by the time I get home." So Bob Bob, whoever said "obligatory to state duration" really means "this pattern is only really useful with a duration."

@AndyBonner does the same apply to future perfect continuous that I don't have to state duration for instance "I will have been playing when they visit" would be fine with no duration?

@BobBob The modal sense, "I want you to," is important here. "I will have been" loses that, which changes everything. In fact, I take back what I said earlier: Duration or not, I just can't imagine using perfect continuous along with a modal sense in a future-oriented construction. I wouldn't say "I want you to have been studying for 2 hours when I get home," I would say "I want you to have studied for 2 hours when I get home." Even if I expect more studying after I get home, I'd just use past perfect like that.

I think I've thought about it long enough to make an answer...

There's a big difference. For one thing, #1 ("I want you to be doing your homework when I get home") is reasonably idiomatic, but #2 ("I want you to have been doing your homework when I get home"). If it were, its meaning would differ in the same way as any shift from progressive to perfect progressive.
Let's try that with something simpler, present tense and non-modal.

"I am doing my homework" = "My state at this exact present moment is one of studying."
"I have been doing my homework" = "My state at this present moment is affected in some way by a recent* past state of studying."

Similarly, example #1 means "When I get home, I want to find you studying," and if #2 were idiomatic, it would mean "When I get home, I want to find that you have been studying." (Actually, that phrasing is plenty idiomatic.)
The problem with #2, as given, is that the modal sense ("I want you to") just doesn't make much sense with a continuous form. Think about it as an imperative: "Hey you! Study!" vs. "Hey you! Be studying!" It's confusing enough when we use a past tense in a future construction—"When I get home, in the future, I want to find that your then-present state will be defined by what will by then be your recent past (but is still in the closer future)"—and for any scenario that I can imagine, that "state" would simply be referenced with a past perfect verb, not continuous: I want you to have studied when I get home. This is suitable whether "studied" is an activity that is supposed to have concluded (I want you to have done all your studying) or whether the point is just the some of the activity happened ("I want you to have thought about this decision overnight"). (For this reason, if I want you to have finished all your studying, it might be best for me to say exactly that so you don't do just a part of it and then say "I studied!")
I could imagine using perfect continuous in a future construction without a modal sense. "I'm taking the pies out of the freezer. By the time we're done with dinner, they will have been thawing for about two hours and should be perfect."

* What does "recent" past mean? Well, perfect continuous is a wonderfully vague construction and can be very flexible, and the context will clarify (or will be asked for more clarification as needed). "I've been studying for two hours and need a break"—implies that the "recent past" of studying extends right up to the present moment. "I speak English well because I've been studying for five years"—doesn't mean that I've had my nose in the books for every moment of those five years; the different context makes it an "off-and-on" activity over a long duration. The period of studying is again understood to extend right to the present. "I need to make new friends because I've been living in another country for two years"—this could reasonably be said days, weeks, maybe even months after returning.

Thank you very much for that long and really informative answer. I understand my example was let's call it strange. I want to ask one more question just to be sure. "It seems to have been raining there a lot whenever I visit that place". The difference between my example and "to be raining" is that my example doesn't really specify if rain is still ongoing once i am there it may be but doesn't have to. Correct? As I understand my new example doesn't really need to state duration to be correct grammatically?

@BobBob That's unrelated enough from this one to deserve its own question; no modal sense, no future. I'd say there's an important understood context: "It seems to have been raining a lot there lately." It's a lot like "studying English": an activity that's understood to have been off-and-on, not absolutely continuous, but generally defines a certain amount of recent past. If you don't specify duration ("It's been raining a lot this week,") then one is usually implied from context or a reasonable one is assumed (a few weeks, in topics of weather?).

Big thanks to you. If you don't mind. Last short question. Thanks. As I understood it is possible not to state duration. Is the same possible with future perfect continuous. "I will have been sleeping when you get home". Could it be valid with no duration as well or does it really really need one?

@BobBob That specific example doesn't make much sense without a duration. I could imagine "I will have been gardening when you get home, so let me shower before you hug me."
